# View too large to fit into drawing cache

Tags: java, android, image, caching, android-camera

The camera function really drive me crazy! I have activity A and Activity B where the selected image will return from Activity B to A. I use the code below but it not works for every cases.  Some selected image can show in Activity A but some are not.

**Activity B**

```
 b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
  @Override

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == 1) {
                  // Take photo

            } else if (requestCode == 2) {

                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                // h=1;
                //imgui = selectedImage;
                String[] filePath = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
                Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePath, null, null, null);
                c.moveToFirst();
                int columnIndex = c.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]);
                String picturePath = c.getString(columnIndex);
                c.close();
                Bitmap thumbnail = (BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
                Log.w("path of image ******", picturePath + "");
                b.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
            }


        }
        else
        {
            finish();
        }


    }

}

   ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() // Return to Activity A
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                b.layout(0, 0, b.getMeasuredWidth(), b.getMeasuredHeight());
                b.buildDrawingCache(true);
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                if (b.getDrawingCache() != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getDrawingCache());
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                    }
                    Global.img = bitmap;
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
```

**Activity A**

```
  viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            if(data!=null&&data.hasExtra("text")) {
                c = data.getStringExtra("text");
                txt1.setText(c);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img); // Not all image can be displayed here !!!
            }


        }
        else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

**Global.java**

```
public class Global {

    static Bitmap img;
}
```

> 11-08 01:39:19.820    8675-8675/com.example.project.project W/path of
>   image ******﹕ /storage/extSdCard/DCIM/100MSDCF/DSC00050.jpg 11-08
>   01:39:27.730    8675-8675/com.example.project.project W/View﹕ View too
>   large to fit into drawing cache, needs 12582912 bytes, only 3686400
>   available 11-08 01:39:27.730    8675-8675/com.example.project.project
>   W/View﹕ View too large to fit into drawing cache, needs 12582912
>   bytes, only 3686400 available

**activity_b**

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="574dp"
        android:layout_height="523dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_x="6dp"
        android:layout_y="0dp" />
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="66dp"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/editText38"
        android:layout_x="4dp"
        android:hint="Add caption"
        android:layout_y="491dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cancel"
        android:id="@+id/button15"
        android:layout_x="8dp"
        android:layout_y="571dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="174dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="OK"
        android:id="@+id/button16"
        android:layout_x="195dp"
        android:layout_y="571dp" />
</AbsoluteLayout>
```

**activity_a**

```
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="47dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="Add Project"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="170dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
        android:text="Project"
        android:id="@+id/textView48"
        android:layout_x="47dp"
        android:layout_y="82dp" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Amount"
        android:id="@+id/editText36"
        android:layout_x="47dp"
        android:layout_y="133dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save"
        android:id="@+id/button17"
        android:layout_x="47dp"
        android:layout_y="560dp" />

    <ImageButton
        android:layout_width="66dp"
        android:layout_height="54dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:src="@mipmap/camerabutton"
        android:layout_x="277dp"
        android:layout_y="149dp"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="293dp"
        android:layout_height="283dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_x="41dp"
        android:layout_y="223dp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="304dp"
        android:layout_height="51dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView57"
        android:layout_x="43dp"
        android:layout_y="490dp" />

</AbsoluteLayout>
```

The selected image firstly will placed in `imageView3`(Activity B). When `button16` is clicked, the image will display in `imageView2`.(Activity A)

Comment: can you show your layout.xml file where you set Image Bitmap having ImageView

Comment: @PavitraKansara hi,thanks for your response. i have edited my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the scaled bitmap to set in the `ImageView`. This way you will get the scaled down Bitamp.
So in your code where you set the `Bitmap` to `ImageView`, call the `getScaledBitmap` and provide the input args for width and height as per your needs.

```
private Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String picturePath, int width, int height) {
    BitmapFactory.Options sizeOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);

    int inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(sizeOptions, width, height);

    sizeOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    sizeOptions.inSampleSize = inSampleSize;

    return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath, sizeOptions);
}


private int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
                                      int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
    // Raw height and width of image
    final int height = options.outHeight;
    final int width = options.outWidth;
    int inSampleSize = 1;

    if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

        // Calculate ratios of height and width to requested height and width
        final int heightRatio = Math.round((float) height / (float) reqHeight);
        final int widthRatio = Math.round((float) width / (float) reqWidth);

        // Choose the smallest ratio as inSampleSize value, this will
        // guarantee a final image with both dimensions larger than or equal to the
        // requested height and width.
        inSampleSize = heightRatio < widthRatio ? heightRatio : widthRatio;
     }
    return inSampleSize;
}
```

Call the `getScaledBitmap()` with the desired `height` and `width` as per your `View`

```
image.setImageBitmap(getScaledBitmap(picturePath, WIDTH, HEIGHT));
```

Hope it helps.